# How to properly convert date into NSDate? (Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I'm pulling in a contest end date from remote config (a string), and trying to cast it as an NSDate to use in a timer.

```
    let contestEndDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    contestEndDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    contestEndDate = contestEndDateFormatter.date(from: contestEndDateFromRemoteConfig)! as NSDate
```

As you can see in the image, the string "2019-05-29 23:59:59" is definitely in the variable "contestEndDateFromRemoteConfig" (so it's not an issue with remote config); however, I'm obviously doing something wrong because it throws the error "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

I believe the dateFormat is correct and matches the string (which was the suggestion from similar stackoverflow questions), so that shouldn't be the issue either.

Can anybody see why this would be throwing an error?

Thanks in advance for any direction!

Comment: 1. Don't cast to `NSDate`. Leave it as a `Date`. 2. Set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: I don't seem to have any issues.  Maybe use `en_US_POSIX` as rmaddy has suggested.  I also don't see the point of trying to cast the result to `NSDate`, it should be interchangeable

Comment: You guys are geniuses. Thank you!

Added contestEndDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, @MadProgrammer, when I ran it on the simulator, I didn't have any issues either. Only when testing on an actual device the error started happening.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var date = "2019-05-29 23:59:59"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

if let formattedDate = formattedDate {
    print(formattedDate)
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the issue in the question.